# Bootstrap: Resizing background image for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm modifying a Bootstrap template thats using @media(max-width) queries. The background images looks fine in desktop responsive view. But the image is cut off horizontally (left and right) for mobile responsive view as seen below. It looks like even when viewed in responsive design mode or on an iPhone, the desktop media query is still used.

The desktop media query being used for both desktop and mobile is

```
header.carousel {
    height: 80%;
}
```

I tried changing the mobile media query with `!important` but it doesn't appear to force the use of this media query.

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .img-portfolio {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    header.carousel .carousel {
        height: 60%!important;
    }
}
```

I can change the desktop media query height to a lower value that will look correctly on mobile, but then the desktop view will get chopped vertically (top and bottom).

Anyone have a solution?

[image: bootstrap mobile cropped]

The full code is below

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Modern Business (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */


/* Global Styles */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}


/*.navbar-brand.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}*/


/*a.dropdown-toggle*/

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*.navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: 35px;
}*/


/*a.dropdown-toggle {
    font-size: 16px;
}*/

img.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  height: 70px;
  /*line-height: 35px;*/
}


/*a.navbar-brand.title {
    font-size: 20px;
}*/

.img-portfolio {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-hover:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* Home Page Carousel */

header.carousel {
  /*height: 50%;*/
  height: 80%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* 404 Page Styles */

.error-404 {
  font-size: 100px;
}


/* Pricing Page Styles */

.price {
  display: block;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.price sup {
  top: -20px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.period {
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Footer Styles */

footer {
  margin: 50px 0;
}


/* Responsive Styles */

@media(max-width:991px) {
  .customer-img,
  .img-related {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .img-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  header.carousel .carousel {
    height: 60%!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <!--<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link href="styles/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <!--<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Super Service Heating &amp; Cooling</a>-->
        <!--<img src="images/logo-small.png">-->
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo-small.png" class="logo"></a>-->
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand title" href="/">Super Service Heating &amp; Cooling</a>-->
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <!--<a href="about.html">About</a>-->
            <!--<a href="./about/">About</a>-->
            <!--<a href="#">Air Conditioning</a>-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Air Conditioning <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Air Conditioning Repair</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Air Conditioning Installation</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!--<a href="services.html">Services</a>-->
            <!--<a href="#">Heating</a>-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Heating <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Heating Repair</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Heating Installation</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!--<a href="services.html">Services</a>-->
            <!--<a href="#">Heating</a>-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ventilation <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Ventilation Repair</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Ventilation Installation</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!--<a href="services.html">Services</a>-->
            <!--<a href="#">Heating</a>-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Maintenance <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Check-Up</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Tune-Up</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Re-Condition</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Header Carousel -->
  <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <!--<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>-->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/fe503bcecec148e98b8264560b170aa9.jpg/v1/fill/w_1265,h_525,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/fe503bcecec148e98b8264560b170aa9.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <!--<h2>Caption 1</h2>-->
          <h2>Heating</h2>
          <h2>Caption 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <!--<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>-->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/7aa29e_fe789a02d347491da0897a536f102e31~mv2_d_2800_1867_s_2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1265,h_515,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/7aa29e_fe789a02d347491da0897a536f102e31~mv2_d_2800_1867_s_2.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Air Conditioning</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <!--<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>-->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/7aa29e_84f4f5aed8b241ec9a3b88b089f1313e~mv2_d_2800_1869_s_2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1265,h_527,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/7aa29e_84f4f5aed8b241ec9a3b88b089f1313e~mv2_d_2800_1869_s_2.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Maintenance</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </header>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Bootstrap v3.3.7</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i> Free &amp; Open Source</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-compass"></i> Easy to Use</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Portfolio Section -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="page-header">Portfolio Heading</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="portfolio-item.html">
          <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Features Section -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="page-header">Modern Business Features</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>The Modern Business template by Start Bootstrap includes:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Bootstrap v3.3.7</strong>
          </li>
          <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
          <li>Font Awesome v4.2.0</li>
          <li>Working PHP contact form with validation</li>
          <li>Unstyled page elements for easy customization</li>
          <li>17 HTML pages</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, omnis doloremque non cum id reprehenderit, quisquam totam aspernatur tempora minima unde aliquid ea culpa sunt. Reiciendis quia dolorum ducimus unde.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x450" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Call to Action Section -->
    <div class="well">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, expedita, saepe, vero rerum deleniti beatae veniam harum neque nemo praesentium cum alias asperiores commodi.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" href="#">Call to Action</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p>Copyright &copy; Company Name
            <script>
              document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
            </script>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
  <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i need more information about your css and html

Comment: @jbiWeisendorf I've added the full code for review. Thx

Comment: j7an: there is an error in your css

Answer (score 1):

your @media(max-width:767px) is wrong

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
  .img-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  header.carousel .carousel { // header.carousel .fill is necessary
    height: 60%!important;
  }
}
```

I think this helps :) And note: if you adjust the height think then also to the wide

Answer (score 0):

Try using **vh** instead of **percents**.

```
height: 80vh;
```

I made this pen, so you can see how to use vh unit: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqvxgE

vh - calculates height based on your viewport, so the layout should look the same on different viewports - screen resolutions.

More about units in css: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp